# Rails Controller Refactor DRY Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, dry

Im stuck trying to find a way to refactor this ugly controller

```
  def video_games
  @video_games_released = Item.video_games.released.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
  @video_games_coming_soon = Item.video_games.coming_soon.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
  @video_games_unknown = Item.video_games.unknown.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
end

def movies
  @movies_coming_soon = Item.movies.coming_soon.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  } 
  @movies_released = Item.movies.released.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
  @movies_unknown = Item.movies.unknown.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
end

def tv
  @tv_coming_soon = Item.tv.coming_soon.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
  @tv_released = Item.tv.released.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }
  @tv_unknown = Item.tv.unknown.group_by { 
    |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
  }  
end
```

I want to get rid of the duplication espcially my group_by methods

I've tried going into the model and creating a method

```
 def group_by_month
   self.group_by { 
     |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
   } 
 end
```

ive tried scoping it but nothing seems to be working

I'm no rails expert and really trying to learn how to refactor code and keep things dry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [groupupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem
it will give you this functionality on the database level

**That was the easy way**

If you want to do it in a way to learn more about rails

you have an obvious block that you use over and over again

```
{ 
     |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()
   }
```

you can save it and call it when you need it

```
date_group = lambda { |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()}
```

and when you need to use it you can do

```
Item.tv.coming_soon.group_by(&date_group)
```

you may want to save this block in some place that you can easily access

Comment: Thats a good suggestion...but is there not an easy way to refactor this?  Thanks for the heads up on the gem though...I would like to know if there is a good way to refactor this code without the use of a gem though.  Just for learning purposes...thanks!

Comment: add more comments for any more clarification

Comment: thank you thats what i was looking for...whats with the & in front of date_group (&date_group)

Comment: its for passing a block as an argument its ruby syntax

Answer (score 2):

so what i did to refactor this code with the help of khaled_gomaa suggestion was

i created a presenter in

```
app/presenters/items/index_presenter.rb

module Items
class IndexPresenters
  def initialize(item)
    @item = item
  end

   def released
     @item.released.group_by(&date_group)
   end

   def coming_soon
     @item.coming_soon.group_by(&date_group)
   end

   def unknown
     @item.unknown.group_by(&date_group)
   end

   def date_group 
     lambda { |item| [item.release_date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y"), item.time_diff_components].join()}
   end
 end
end
```

then in my controller

```
def video_games
  @presenter = Items::IndexPresenters.new(Item.video_games)
end

def movies
  @presenter = Items::IndexPresenters.new(Item.movies)
end

def tv
  @presenter = Items::IndexPresenters.new(Item.tv)
end
```

and my views

```
%h2 Movies Released
= render 'items', item: @presenter.released
%h2 Movies Coming Soon
= render 'items', item: @presenter.coming_soon
%h2 Movies Unknown
= render 'items', item: @presenter.unknown
```

any further suggestions would be welcomed!  Thank you!